# How to select pandas row with maximum value in one column, from a group of rows that share two common columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The following Pandas DataFrame `df` has  5 columns, colored, while the index numbers are on the very left in black.

[image]

Notice **the last two columns** (let's call them `col4` and `col5`) have static numbers, denoting a segment, group or chunk of the data. Other groups (that change  their static numbers in these two columns) have been hidden from screenshot.

How to single out the row, or index of the row, that has the **largest value in the third column** (called `col3`), circled in black: `1.90977`, conditional on the fact that the last 2 rows are static? In other words, single out the best row in the group

looking for something like this, which doesn't work:

```
df.loc[(df['col3'] == 0.999141) & (df['col4'] == 0.000861559)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not last 2 columns has same values use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for select columns by some precision, also for performance is better select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by mask and column name:

```
df.loc[np.isclose(df['col4'], 0.999141) & np.isclose(df['col5'], 0.000861559), 'col3'].max()
```

For index of maximum value use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[np.isclose(df['col4'], 0.999141) & np.isclose(df['col5'], 0.000861559), 'col3'].idxmax()
```

For select by maximum `col4` and minimum `col5` use:

```
df.loc[df['col4'].eq(df['col4'].max()) & df['col5'].eq(df['col5'].min()), 'col3'].max()

df.loc[df['col4'].eq(df['col4'].max()) & df['col5'].eq(df['col5'].min()), 'col3'].idxmax()
```

Comment: the first solution, like my attempt, fails to recognize anything set to `== 0.999141` or other, despite the number clearly being visible, which is what I don't get

Comment: why are you continuously citing `col2`, when it's only about columns 3,4 and 5?

Comment: @develarist - so last 2 are `col3` and `col4` so previous are not `col2` ? Unfortunately in sample data is not seen columns names, so guessing

Comment: The last 2 are `col4` and `col5`. "How to single out the row, or index of the row, that has the **largest value in the third column** (called `col3`), circled in black: `1.90977`"

Comment: @develarist - oops, sorry, answer was edited.

Comment: @develarist - If in `col4` and `col5` are same values, is necessary use for selecting?

Comment: @develarist - I think you need `df.loc[np.isclose(df['col4'], 0.999141) & np.isclose(df['col5'], 0.000861559), 'col3'].max()`

Comment: this latest single edit was able to single out the correct row. any way to re-phrase (separately without deleting the original)  the same but without stating any values whatsoever. i.e. instead of `0.999141` it will be the maximum value of `col4`, while  instead of `0.000861559` it will be the minimum value of `col5`